# How to match the label of geom_text and point of geom_point closer?

Tags: r, ggplot2

The R code:

```
cn<-rownames(mpg.df)
p4<-mpg.df %>%
  ggplot(aes(displ, hwy, color=cn)) + 
  geom_text(aes(label=cn), size=2, position=position_jitter(width=0.5, height=5)) +
  guides(color=FALSE)
p4
```

By the effect of **jitter**, it seems can't control the relative position between of pair of label of **geom_text** and point of **geom_point**.

Thanks so much!!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! In order to make it easier for us to help you, please also upload example data using e.g. `dput()`, and the plot in question.

Answer (score 0):

If you jitter before `ggplot`, then the same jittering can be had for all geoms.

Data, and showing the problem:

```r
mt <- mtcars[1:10,]
mt$cyl <- factor(mt$cyl)
mt$rowname <- rownames(mt)

ggplot(mt, aes(disp, mpg, color = cyl)) +
  geom_jitter(shape = 21, size = 5, position = position_jitter(width = 20, height = 5)) +
  geom_text(aes(label = substr(rowname, 1, 3)), position = position_jitter(width = 20, height = 5))
```

[image: ggplot with inline jittering, bad]

The fix (I'm assuming you're using `dplyr`):

```r
library(dplyr)
mt %>%
  mutate(
    disp_jtr = jitter(disp),
    mpg_jtr = jitter(mpg)
  ) %>%
  ggplot(aes(disp_jtr, mpg_jtr, color = cyl)) +
  geom_point(shape = 21, size = 5) +
  geom_text(aes(label = substr(rowname, 1, 3)))
```

[image: ggplot with jittering before rendering, fixed]

Comment: Your idea let me realize the nature of jitter. It make a random noise to a certain vector. Thank you so much.